# How to implement max_heapify in heap datastructure in Python

Tags: python, data-structures

The following is a class of heap. I am trying to sort the heap but i have a problem with my `max_heapify` function. I have inserted the values `[10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]` and my heap sort prints the given output. The given output and expected output is given below the class

class of heap

```
class Heap(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = []

    def insert(self, x):
        self.A.append(x)

    def Max(self):
        """
        returns the largest value in an array
        """
        return max(self.A)

    def extractMax(self):
        """
        returns and remove the largest value from an array
        """
        x = max(self.A)
        self.A.remove(x)
        self.max_heapify(0)
        return x;

    def parent(self, i):
        """
        returns the parent index
        """
        i+=1
        i = int(i/2)
        return i

    def left(self, i):
        """
        returns the index of left child
        """
        i = i+1
        i = 2*i
        return i

    def right(self, i):
        """
         returns the index of right child
        """
        i+=1;
        i = 2*i + 1
        return i

    def heap_size(self):
        """
         returns the size of heap
        """

        return len(self.A)

    def max_heapify(self, i):
        """
        heapify the array 
        """
        l = self.left(i)
        r = self.right(i)

        if(l < self.heap_size() and self.A[l] > self.A[i]):
            largest = l
        else:
            largest = i

        if(r < self.heap_size() and self.A[r] > self.A[largest]):
            largest = r


        if largest != i:

            temp = self.A[i]
            self.A[i] = self.A[largest]
            self.A[largest] = temp

            self.max_heapify(largest)


    def build_max_heap(self):

           n = len(self.A)
           n = int(n/2)
           for i in range(n, -1, -1):
               self.max_heapify(i)


    def heap_sort(self):
        """
         sorts the heap
        """

        while self.heap_size() > 0:

                self.build_max_heap()
                temp = self.A[0]
                n = len(self.A) - 1
                self.A[0] = self.A[n]
                self.A[n] = temp
                x = self.A.pop()
                print(x)
                self.max_heapify(0)




h = Heap()
h.insert(10)
h.insert(9)
h.insert(7)
h.insert(6)
h.insert(5)
h.insert(4)
h.insert(3)
h.heap_sort()
```

given output

```
10
7
6
5
4
3
9
```

expected output

```
10
9
7
6
5
4
3
```

Comment: @Grokify thanks for editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to build a max-heap with the root at `A[0]`. If that's correct, then your `left`, `right`, and `parent` index calculations are not correct. You have:

```
def parent(self, i):
    """
    returns the parent index
    """
    i+=1
    i = int(i/2)
    return i

def left(self, i):
    """
    returns the index of left child
    """
    i = i+1
    i = 2*i
    return i

def right(self, i):
    """
     returns the index of right child
    """
    i+=1;
    i = 2*i + 1
    return i
```

So if `i=0`, the left child would be 2, and the right child would be 3. Worse, given `i=3`, `parent` will return 2. So you have the case where `parent(right(i)) != i`. That's never going to work.

The correct calculations are:

```
left = (2*i)+1
right = (2*i)+2
parent = (i-1)/2
```

I don't know why your `extractMax` is calling `max(self.A)`. You already know that the maximum element is at `A[0]`. To extract the maximum item, all you need to do is:

```
returnValue = save value at self.A[0]
take last item in the array and place at self.A[0]
decrease length of array
maxHeapify(0)
```

I've used pseudo-code because I'm not particularly comfortable with Python.

The loop inside your `heapSort` method is seriously non-optimum. You're calling `self.build_max_heap` at each iteration. You don't need to do that. If `extractMax` is working correctly, all you have to do is:

```
while self.heap_size() > 0:
    temp = self.extractMax()
    print temp
```

Now, if you want to sort the array in-place, so that `self.A` itself is sorted, that's a bit more tricky. But it doesn't look like that's what you're trying to do.